# What do you do when Ubuntu hangs/lags? Ctrl+Alt+Del?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Generally, I think Linux should be stable? But recently, my Ubuntu was hanging or lagging. Mouse moves but not responding to clicks. On Windows, I would use Ctrl+Alt+Del and stop any unresponsive apss. I wonder if theres a replacement in Ubuntu for Ctrl+Alt+Del? OR what will u do when Ubuntu hangs?

Comment: Jiewmeng, please be sure to check that you are not posting duplicate questions. It seems like many of your questions are duplicates.